# Remove 'Create and Edit' from many2one field(lot_id) for type 'outgoing' using fields_view_get method

Tags: python, odoo

Is there a way that I can remove 'create and edit' in many2one field (lot_id) when the 'type' is 'outgoing' (for delivery - Sales Order)?

EDIT:

**Modified:**

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(stock_transfer_details, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    #codes here

            if view_type == 'form' and is_outgoing == 'outgoing':
               doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
               for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='lot_id']"):
                  node.set('no_create', "true")
                  node.set('no_create_edit', "true")
                  setup_modifiers(node, res['fields']['lot_id'])
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

**stock_transfer_details.xml (original)**

```
<record id="view_stock_enter_transfer_details" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Enter transfer details</field>
  <field name="model">stock.transfer_details</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Transfer details" version="7">
      <field name="picking_source_location_id" invisible="True"/>
      <field name="picking_destination_location_id" invisible="True"/>
        <group string="Products To Move">
          <div class="oe_grey" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot">
                Setting a product and a source package means that the product will be taken
                out of the package.  
          </div>
        </group>
        <group>
          <field name="item_ids"
              context="{'default_sourceloc_id':picking_source_location_id,
                          'default_destinationloc_id':picking_destination_location_id}" nolabel="1">
            <tree string="Inventory Details" editable="bottom" >
              <field name="package_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot"/>
              <field name="product_id" required="True"  context="{'uom':product_uom_id}" on_change="product_id_change(product_id,product_uom_id,context)"/>
              <field name="quantity"/>
              <button name="split_quantities" string="Split" type="object" icon="STOCK_PREFERENCES" attrs="{'invisible': [('quantity', '=', 1)]}"/>
              <field name="product_uom_id" options="{&quot;no_open&quot;: True}" groups="product.group_uom"/>
              <field name="sourceloc_id" domain="[('id', 'child_of', parent.picking_source_location_id)]"/>
              <field name="destinationloc_id" domain="[('id', 'child_of', parent.picking_destination_location_id)]"/>
              <field name="result_package_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot" context="{'location_id': destinationloc_id}"/>
              <button name="put_in_pack" string="Pack" type="object" icon="terp-product" attrs="{'invisible': [('result_package_id', '!=', False)]}" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot"/>
              <field name="lot_id" groups="stock.group_production_lot" domain="[('product_id','=?', product_id)]" context="{'product_id': product_id}"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
      </group>....
```

Still not working. How can I locate `lot_id` field in tree view?

Comment: For which version of Odoo are you face trouble or need solution ?

Comment: try to debug your code. put a breakpoint at the for and see the content of *res['arch']* if it does not contain the field *lot_id* then there's something wrong with the view, not with the code.

Comment: Hi Sir, when I tried to debug it, there's no lot_id. Only the form string appears. FYI, the field lot_id is inside in a tree view after the form view, does it matter? Above is the xml code (original) and xml that I inherited..

Comment: So, problem is the *lot_id* field is inside the tree, thus it is not directly inside *res['arch']*: if you go in debug into the *fields_view_get* you will be able to see a json structure into *res* object (but not inside 'arch'). I'm not able to tell you the right structure because today I'm homesick, thus I can't check at work the source code I used, but I used this very same mechanism and it worked for me weeks ago.

Comment: @Anonymous101 I changed my answer, this should work. But I want to tell you, you didn't need me to accomplish that: if you did what I suggested (debug the *fields_view_get* in order to find where the *lot_id* field was) you would have been already done with that days ago...

Comment: i suppose it is because you are into another view from the same model which doesn't contain the *item_ids* field. just modify the code in order to check its existence before using it.

Comment: @Anonymous101  Thanks, Happy new year to you too. What you need to do is insert a breakpoint into *doc = etree.XML(...* line and check if *res* contains the structure in the code. if not you can just use an *if*

Comment: @Anonymous101 I do not understand why you removed my answer as solution.

Comment: It is not appropriate to damage your question like you did in [Revision 8](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34171367/revisions).  A number of people have put effort into helping you.  It is discourteous to treat them like this. (A number of the prior edits are dubious too; I think Revision 5 is probably the best version of the question — but I'm not sure or I'd've rolled back.)

Answer (score 2):

**many2one widget (default)**

**Options** : Other possible options you can use with this widget.

- no_quick_create - remove the Create and edit... option.
- no_create_edit - remove the Create "foo" option.
- no_create - no_quick_create and no_create_edit combined.
- no_open - in read mode: do not render as a link.

**Example:**

```
<field name="field_name" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}"/>
```

You can refer it from [Ludwik Trammer's post](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/form-widgets-many2one-fields-options-odoo.html)

Alessandro Ruffolo suggested right way you may follow it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir, but I still have a problem with this one.

Answer (score 1):

What I'do is to change the context of the model when the form is called (e.g. into the action), to pass the type (incoming/outgoing) and then overriding fields_view_get in order to modify the field lot_id adding the *options* attribute as @user00000341 said, only when type is 'outgoing'.

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(material_paper, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    type = context.get('type', False)
    if view_type == 'form' and type == 'outgoing':
        doc = etree.XML(res['fields']['item_ids']['views']['tree']['arch'])
        update = False
        for field in doc.xpath("//field[@name='lot_id']"):
            field.attrib['options'] = "{'no_create_edit': True}"
            update = True
        if update:
            res['fields']['item_ids']['views']['tree']['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

Comment: Hi! can you please give me an example? I'm not familiar with fields_view_get

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<field name="many2one field name" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
```

Comment: In transferring for incoming and outgoing products, the both use the same view. So if do that, the incoming will also be affected.

Comment: hi try this one options="{'no_create': [('type', '=', 'outgoing')]}"  may be it's possible

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but the answer of Alessandro while being right doesn't really explain the problem here.

Fields view get is a method that will fetch at once almost all the possible views that are required in the form of a tree. The problem is that when you check the `arch` of the return of `fields_view_get` you'll see that `item_ids` is a simple field and there is no tree view attached to it.

The reason is that all sub-views are inserted in their respective field in the `fields` attribute of the returned value. This is also a recursive method so each sub field can have any number of sub-views attached to them.

One of the reason why Allessandro's answer could fail to work is if the view is already loaded somewhere else in the tree. While looking at `res['fields']['item_ids']['views']['tree']['arch']` should work. In more complicated cases, the view could have been loaded previously somewhere else. In those cases, you'd have to check for all the field/views/tree sub trees to change any field that match the field you want to extend using lxml.